# Any example on how to persists Object with a DAL using Datasets?

Tags: c#

I read this article:
http://blogs.objectsharp.com/CS/blogs/barry/archive/2008/04/27/the-entity-framework-vs-the-data-access-layer-part-0-introduction.aspx

It mentions Dataadapter & Dataset as possible DAL with others like Entity Framework and Linq to SQL.

Where can I find examples with Datasets ? I mean a "well-designed" DAL so that Business Layer Objects is independant from the DAL. The example here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cicciotopone/DALbasedondataSets12012005003132AM/DALbasedondataSets.aspx doesn't seem to fit this criteria or maybe I am wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

[Data Access Layer based on dataSet](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cicciotopone/DALbasedondataSets12012005003132AM/DALbasedondataSets.aspx)s

Comment: Thanks for the link but this DAL doesn't seem to be independant from the Business Layer. Or tell me how do I persist an Object Class with it ?

Comment: or rather the other way round: the Business Layer is coupled too much with the DAL.